# Grammar by example

Tags: programming-languages, parsing, grammar

Is there an automated approach to generate a grammar (which could be used later in a compiler tool such as ANTLR or similar) from given examples of a language?

With more detail:
assumed a technical language such as Java, C or (in my case) MQSC, and some source files of that language, is there an automation to derive tokens out of the existing sources as well as in a second step identifying variables etc, and later on the grammer in some form? 
Target would be a grammar description for that language for example for ANTLR.

Or is the only way for that by doing it yourself?

I think this is a general question on all (programming) languages; however, my personal case deals with reading and parsing a very large and complex MQ configuration from IBM's MQSC.

Comment: Would a [railroad grammar diagraming tool](http://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) be the sort of thing you're talking about?

Comment: There are multiple grammars that match a given collection of texts. Consider `A := aAb | ab;` and `A := aaAbb | aabb` and the examples `aabb`, `aaaabbbb`, etc. How would you decide *which* to generate?

Comment: I know there are several variants, but for me, one which could be implemented in ANTLR or similar would be just ok.

Comment: @CandiedOrange if I could enter just one or more files in the language where I need a grammar, that would be fine. However, I am not sure whether the tool you linked supports this approach.

Comment: @Walter not sure what you mean by "enter just one or more files in the language". How are files "entered" in a language?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I mean something like "grammarGenerator < aFile.mqsc" thus reading a given file in a language into the solution i search for.

Comment: @Walter you mean you feed a program examples of a language and expect the program to spit out the languages grammar?

Comment: @CandiedOrange well, in general this is not easily possilble. However, I search a tool that supports this process, that means identifiying tokens at first; suggesting grammar rules second; while I would restructure rules in the mentioned iterative way until it works.

Comment: @walter Actually I can prove it's impossible. There are competitions to make two different languages compile into two different programs from exactly the same source code.

Comment: As a concrete example: Which of C++ or C# or Java does `class SomeClass { int SomeMethod(int param) { return 42; } };` belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn’t really a way to do this.

I mean, technically, you can take any grammar and combine it with another and end up with something like

`S ::= example1
S ::= example2`

With enough examples, you can maybe identify common sequences, but they don’t *mean* anything. Are all these common sequences identifiers? Keywords? Magic strings that people happen to use commonly?

Algorithms won’t know.

And since these grammars are likely to be infinitely generative, no amount of examples can possibly fully define your grammar. The algorithm would need to make correct assumptions, or would only know about a subset of the language.

Comment: Well my idea is to do this in an iterated way. Something like "the tool" reads an example, supports me in identifiying tokens, generates a suggested grammar, then allows me to restructure that. And then iterate.

Comment: @walter - I cannot imagine a scenario where this is less work than just googling up the existing language’s grammar. Or reverse engineering it’s compiler. Or making a new grammar from scratch based on human analysis.

Comment: I understand. From a technical point, I did not found a well suited grammar; and I cannot reverse engineer a compiler. So the last option is the one which will drive me into a technical solution. From an academic perspective, it might be an interesting thing... (having had compiler construction 30 years ago...)

Comment: Another alternative is that the grammar `S = L*` for all possible characters `L` matches all strings in the language – but also all strings outside the language. To prevent that, any machine learning kind of solution would also need an input corpus of invalid examples that must not be matched. Together with an optimization goal of finding the smallest grammar that matches the input, I could imagine a genetic programming kind of solution. But just writing down the grammar yourself is much easier than gathering a suitable corpus.